# How to remove team administrators (that are not members) using Azure CLI?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-cli

So I'm creating a script in powershell to reset the project's team members as well as the admins, but currently I can only remove the admins if they are members for the team. Most of the projects that will be affected by my script have team admins that are not team members... I can't seem to figure it out. Any help? Thank's!

Answer (score 0):

Project administrators must be in the Project Administrators group of the project, so we can remove administrator through the following two azure cli.

[Get Project Administrators group id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/add-manage-security-groups?view=azure-devops#example-2):

```
az devops security group list --project xxx --output table
```

[image]

[Remove member from Project Administrators group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/add-manage-security-groups?view=azure-devops#remove-a-member-from-a-group):

```
az devops security group membership remove --group-id --member-id
```

- group-id: Required. Descriptor of the group from which member needs
  to be removed.
- member-id: Required. Descriptor of the group or email address of the
  user to be removed.

Comment: Hello. Thank you so much for your answer! I've must have expressed myself wrong, but what I want to do is to remove the administrators from a team when neither of the admins is a member for the team. How can I get the member Id  if they are not members of the team?

Comment: mermber Id can also be email address, please see the last line of my answer.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer but sadly it didn't quite help. There's this one team on the project that has administrators that aren't members of the said team. Now, I want to get the information of the admins (user info) to be able to remove them from being team admins. They are not members of the team so I can't obtain their info through the list team members command, so how do I get their descriptor? I won't have info about who the team admins are, I need my script to check if the team has admins and if so to remove them.